# question regarding index errors and division

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists and I wanted to create generate the quotients using a for loop. Specifically, I would want to have .5 and .25 and .125 and in that order. Of course, I could just take these values and determine the quotients manually, but I am looking at this from the perspective of someone who is taking their first stab at learning Python. I have read some other articles on for loops, but do not see why the below produces :  index error: list index out of range. Thus, I am looking not only for the modification of this code but also a reasonable explanation as to why there is such an error.

```
x=[2,4,16]
y=[4,16,128]
for i in y:
    y[i]/x
```

Comment: `for i in y` what do you think `i` contains? (ps. its not index numbers)

Comment: By doing `for i in y:` you are *directly* iterating over the elements of y. You need `enumerate` for your purpose. Or even better `zip`

Comment: This question has been previously marked as off-topic. I believe it's the same you in another name.

Comment: What is wrong directly iterating over the elements of y? I do not get that

Comment: @Jack nothing, until you type this. `y[i]`. Think what value `i` has. What does that resolve to?

Comment: i is regarding each element in y....it resolves to  4 and then after another run of the for loop, it resolves to 16, and then finally after another run of the loop it refers to 128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is to `zip` both lists then apply division over the given iteration values:

```
x=[2,4,16]
y=[4,16,128]
for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
    print(xi/yi)
```

That yields:

0.5
0.25
0.125

In order to understand what `zip` is doing:
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following:

```
x=[2,4,16]
y=[4,16,128]
for i in y:
    print(f"i: {i}")
    print(f"y: {y}")
```

This is the output:

```
i: 4
y: [4, 16, 128]
i: 16
y: [4, 16, 128]
i: 128
y: [4, 16, 128]
```

You are looking for `y[4]` in the first loop, but it doesn't exist. If you want to loop through the list you can do this:

```
x=[2,4,16]
y=[4,16,128]
for i in range(len(y)):
    print(f"i: {i}")
    print(y[i])
```

Output:

```
i: 0
4
i: 1
16
i: 2
128
```

Comment: what is the meaning of f in print(f"i: {i}")

Comment: also this is not dividing anything. this just re-lists everything in a different way

Comment: `print(f"i: {i}")` is a f-string. It's a way to format print statements. And it's not dividing anything because I'm showing you how to correctly index through a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating over the index, you are iterating with the values

```
for i in y:
   y/x[?]
```

If you want to iterate with indexes you could do that with enumerate

```
for index, value in enumerate(y):
    y[index]/x[index]
```

Comment: You should use `value/x[index]`